# Least complicated way to get full file paths with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, security, google-chrome

This has been asked a lot of times already: I need to get the full file path via a web-page. The use case is an application running on the same machine as the browser (i.e. the application starts a local HTTP server and fires up the browser.) File-paths are of course valid and the same for both client/server now. The use case it that the user selects a file and then the server process does some computation on it, and the input files are typically large (read: several GiB in size.)

The easiest thing would be to directly access the path using , but for security reasons, this is disabled. I'm looking now for the least intrusive workaround to this problem. The target browser in question is Chrome. I'm fine if the user has to click "accept" once on some security warning, as long as I can ensure that it won't appear again.

Do I have to write an extension, NSPlugin, can I use some special header magic to mark my page as "local", is there some security setting I can set? The less the client has to do the better, and I would prefer some "click here to allow access ..." solution above everything else. Can I directly install an extension from the server process that would do this (after the user clicks accept?)

Is it possible to do this with a Java applet/Flash? That would be the easiest solution, and clients are guaranteed to have Flash installed (as it is bundled in Chrome...)

Comment: IE allows active -x ... 
But for chrome I don't know..

Comment: I would build this functionality into the server side. In other words, provide the client with a way to "browse" their local filesystem through server operations.

Comment: Yeah, that starts to look easier than having a plugin/extension/applet whatever client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Java applet for tasks like this and self-sign it. User will have to allow it to run, but then you will be able to access applet's function that will return file path string via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly file io on the client's system is forbidden from JavaScript.  If this wasn't the case it would be absolutely trivial to hack every web browser that visits your website.

Battlefiled 3 is controlled though the browser.  To do this EA wrote a browser extension for the top three browsers.  But that's resource intensive.   If you just care about chrome you can use an addon, and for that i suggest using the [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/).

And as MOleYArd said, Java is a good solution and probably more common than an extension or addon.